# Titanium error in retrieving rows

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

getting error when retrieving the datas from the row using an id and displaying it in the textfield in next page..and another error is all the rows are getting deleted when passing id for a specific row..

**Here is the coding:**

```
var data = [];

var db = Titanium.Database.open('trip');

db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtrip (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, triplabel TEXT,tripname TEXT,destination TEXT,fromdate TEXT,todate TEXT)');
//db.execute('INSERT INTO newtrip(triplabel,tripname,destination,fromdate,todate) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',"British museum","mytrip","london","12-10-2014","12-12-2014");
//db.execute('DELETE FROM newtrip');
var resultrows = db.execute('SELECT destination,fromdate,todate FROM newtrip');

while (resultrows.isValidRow()) {

    //var res=
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        rightImage : '/images/right1.png',

        layout : 'absolute'
    });

    var tripnamelabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        //text : 'Buckingham Palace',
        text : resultrows.fieldByName('destination'),
        color : theme_style,
        font : {
            fontSize : '16dp',
            fontWeight : 'bold'
        },

        top : '10dp',
        left : '10dp',
        //right:'30dp'
    });

    var gettablecount = resultrows.rowCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < gettablecount; i++) {
        var data_edit = [];
        var imgedit = Ti.UI.createButton({

            backgroundImage : '/images/list_edit.png',
            // left:'200dp',
            top : '20dp',
            width : wb,
            height : hb,
            // bottom:10,
            right : '20dp',
            onClick : "edit",
            rowid : resultrows.fieldByName('id')
        });
            if (resultrows.isValidRow()) {
                imgedit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    var db = Titanium.Database.open('trip');

                    if (e.source.onClick == "edit") {
                        var x = db.execute('SELECT * FROM newtrip WHERE id=' + rowid);
                        //alert(x);
                        var createnewWindowback = require('ui/apppage5');
                        //the name of the url you wish to move
                        new createnewWindowback(e.source.rowid).open();
                        win.close();
                    }
                    resultrows.close();
                    db.close();

                });

        }

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < gettablecount; i++) {

        var imgdelete = Ti.UI.createButton({

            backgroundImage : '/images/delete_ic.png',
            // left:'240dp',
            top : '20dp',
            width : wb,
            height : hb,
            //bottom:'20dp',
            right : '60dp',
            onClick : "delete",
            rowid : resultrows.fieldByName('id')
        });

        imgdelete.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var db = Titanium.Database.open('trip');

            if (e.source.onClick == "delete") {
                var x = db.execute('DELETE FROM newtrip WHERE id=' + rowid);
                alert("you have just clicked the delete button");
            }
            resultrows.next();
            db.close();

        });
    }
    var fromdate = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        //text : '10.11.2014',
        text : resultrows.fieldByName('fromdate'),
        color : 'Black',
        font : {
            fontSize : '13dp',
            fontWeight : 'bold'
        },
        top : '40dp',
        left : '10dp',
        right : '10dp',
        bottom : '20dp'
    });

    var dash = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : '-',
        color : 'Black',
        font : {
            fontSize : '15dp',
            fontWeight : 'bold'
        },
        top : '40dp',
        left : '80dp',
        right : '10dp',
        bottom : '20dp'
    });

    var todate = Ti.UI.createLabel({

        text : resultrows.fieldByName('todate'),
        color : 'Black',
        font : {
            fontSize : '13dp',
            fontWeight : 'bold'
        },
        top : '40dp',
        left : '90dp',
        right : '10dp',
        bottom : '20dp'
    });
    row.add(tripnamelabel);
    row.add(imgedit);
    row.add(imgdelete);
    row.add(fromdate);
    row.add(dash);
    row.add(todate);
    row.className = 'control';
    data.push(row);
    resultrows.next();
}

resultrows.close();
db.close();
triplistview.setData(data);
```

Comment: what is your table structure and how do you populate it ?

Comment: plz find my updated code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you not able to fetch data according to **id** field because you fetch the data in `resultrows` variable as :

```
var resultrows = db.execute('SELECT destination,fromdate,todate FROM newtrip');
```

So here you do not fetch the **id** column. But you use it at :

```
rowid : resultrows.fieldByName('id') // in : var imgedit
```

Hence `rowid` for `var imgedit` would be null/undefined. You should modify your `SELECT` query as :

```
var resultrows = db.execute('SELECT id,destination,fromdate,todate FROM newtrip');
```

**Edit :** Under click listener of `imgedit` you have :

```
var x = db.execute('SELECT * FROM newtrip WHERE id=' + rowid);
```

But there is no variable `rowid` defined, hence error is thrown. Make following changes ( `rowid` changed to `e.source.rowid`) :

```
var x = db.execute('SELECT * FROM newtrip WHERE id=' + e.source.rowid);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will give this a try and will let you know

Comment: Have made he change and its still the same :(